# What does int A[]={} mean in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I came across this piece of code. It doesn't give an error, but what exactly does it mean?

```
int A[]={};
```

EDIT: I had to edit this post because some of you asked for context, compiler and so on..

I do not know much about compilers but i managed to found the version i'm using "gcc (tdm-1) 4.9.2".

I have tried the code myself and it did run correctly, i was also able to read and write on the array. My question is : What exactly happens when i declare such an array ?

Comment: an empty array...

Comment: Does this even compile???

Comment: It is a grammar error. An initialiser list must not be empty.

Comment: It is an error in C because empty initializers are invalid, but it might mean something in C++...

Answer (score 4):

```
int A[]={};
```

is illegal in C. Empty initializers are not valid.
See [C11 draft, 6.7.9 Initialization](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9).

Comment: There are so many compilers out there, written to so many different standards (or no standard at all) that the statement "is illegal in C" makes no practical sense. You at least have to specify the name of a standard. Suggest editing to add in the name of the standard you referred to in the next sentence.

Comment: @T.E.D. The link I added (C11 draft) sufficiently clarifies it (any potential ambiguity), I believe.

Comment: @T.E.D. If question is tagged [c], without mentioning platform or standard version, we assume that question is about lastest version of the C standard.

Comment: @T.E.D.: There is exactly **one** C standard and exactly **one** valid version of the standard. So it is very clear what is meant.

Comment: @T.E.D. What is assumed when a question is tagged C is evident from the C tag usage wiki: stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info

Comment: @Lundin - That's not in the tag summary, and not clear from skimming the (very long) tag wiki either. So you're telling me if someone comes in with C code from an old compiler they don't know much about, tag it as "C" because that's as specific as they can get, they're liable to get told their code isn't really C? Community standards are community standards I guess, but it seems like a situation ripe for confusion. And what's the point of having a separate C11 tag, if the C tag means the same thing?

Comment: @T.E.D.: That's why [ask] tells users to provide all relevant information. [Ignorantia legis non excusat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignorantia_juris_non_excusat)!

Comment: @T.E.D. It explicitly says that unless a specific standard is mentioned, the latest standard is assumed. Thus non-standard extensions are not assumed. This is not unique to C questions, but pretty much the community consensus for all programming language questions on SO. If you don't agree with the community, feel free to raise debate on meta.

Comment: @Lundin Fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

It means nothing, it is not valid C.

C11 6.7.9 states that the two following forms are valid:

```
{ initializer-list } 
{ initializer-list , }
```

where `initializer-list` is defined as one of the following:

```
designationopt initializer
initializer-list , designationopt initializer
```

This could either be an assignment expression or a C99 designated initializer. An empty initializer list is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It is defining an empty array of type `int`.

Comment: It is not standard C.

Answer (score 0):

You should show some more context, and mention which compiler was being used.

I don't think that code compiles with a standards-compliant compiler, the empty initializer list makes it invalid.

Comment: The empty brackets `[]` are not the problem here.

Comment: Ehm, an empty initialiser is always wrong. Call it a defect in the standard (I think it would be straight-forward and useful), but that's how it is.

Comment: @Olaf I truly suck today. Thanks again.